# How to use a script on another person's page?

Tags: javascript

Since copy-pasting is lame, I decided to make a script that iterates on a repetitive class, gather the infos I need and put them in a big String.

But now that i have the code, what are the solutions to use it on a webpage that isn't mine?

Thanks for the help.

Side note : final code looks something like this (this one is just a sample) :

```
function creationChaine(){

var chaine ="";
$( ".iteratingClass" ).each(function( index ) {
  console.log( index + ": " + $( this ).text() );
   chaine += "var1"+";"+"var2"+";"+"var3"+";"+\n;
});
return chaine;
}

function(){
var resultat = creationChaine();
$("#result").append("<p>"+resultat+"<p>");
}
```

Comment: Either create a Chrome app, where you can execute everything you need, or just copy paste it in the javascript terminal.

Comment: I think i should try to dig on the Chrome app idea (which i know nothing about) cause the script has t be quite user friendly since he won't be used by IT pros :)

Comment: Yep then I recommend a chrome app, its quite easy actually.

Comment: Check: https://developer.chrome.com/apps/first_app

Comment: Yup i did give a quick look, but does it allow me to run a script that runs on someone else webpage? There is a point i must be missing i guess...

Comment: It runs on the page that is active when you click a button (in the chrome toolbar). To always run a script on somebody else's page (without the user knowing) is obviously not possible, and if it is possible (script injection) it is not legal.

Comment: ooh okay so it allows to run a script manually on an existing page, which is exactly what i need ! thanks a lot i will look further on it!